# use a picture box on a panel

Tags: c#, panel, picturebox

I need some help. I'm working on a chess game. I created my chess board on a panel, with pictureBox. As the code below

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {

                    PictureBox boardcase = new PictureBox();
                    boardcase.Size = new Size(100, 100);
                    //if (i == j) { boardcase.BackColor = Color.White; }
                    if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) { boardcase.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue; }
                    else { boardcase.BackColor = Color.Gray; }
                    boardcase.Location = new Point(i * (boardcase.Width + 5) + 45, j * (boardcase.Height + 5) + 15);
                    panel1.Controls.Add(boardcase);

                }

            }
```

Then, I would like to know how I can use individually each pictureBox that i created, outside this block. 
thanks a lot

Comment: Give boardcase a unique name, then you can reference it in the panel1.Controls collection.

Comment: Or add them to a List or an Array, maybe a 2D array..

Comment: It depends on how you plan on using them. @LarsTech 's solution will work for some cases but be highly awkward for others.

Comment: Note that LarsTech taks about the Name property not the variable names!

Answer (score 0):

Haha, ok.I used @TaW 's solution in comment section. and this is it… I just created a PictureBox List as : `List<PictureBox> plateau = new List<PictureBox>();` and assigned each boardcase to the list in my For Loop. `plateau.Add(boardcase);` Then I can call `plateau[i]` in my code. :-) Thanks guys.